# Could not find jar file soaptest.api for webservice automation using parasoft soatest

Tags: java, jar, soa, parasoft

In help of parasoft soatest it is given to use to soaptest.api jar file but its not bundled in soatest jar files , and I am not able to find it to downlaod it

Answer (score 1):

The jar needed is webking.jar, found here:

C:[SOATEst install folder][version]\eclipse\plugins\com.parasoft.xtest.libs.web_[version]\root

Add it to your project build path and the import should work as expected